# Accidentally removed cloth preset, how can I restore it?

Tags: workflow

I accidentally clicked the 'remove preset' button and now I am missing "rubber".  Is there a way to restore the preset?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually tried removing the rubber preset in 2.75 just to see what will be the best way to restore it, but it wouldn't really let me remove it at all. It's still there even after I pressed the remove button.

But anyway, in any other version, try to [load factory settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:DE/2.6/Manual/Preferences#Load_Factory_Settings) and see if that helps. If not, take this as a great opportunity to update to the latest version of Blender!