# Cloth simulation presets are gone, how do I get them back?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to use one of the cloth presets in the Simulations tab, but I've accidentally deleted a couple of the presets and I don't know how to get them back. I've tried restarting blender with a new file, but the cloth sim. still didn't have the Presets. And **I even Tried to Load Factory Settings** [as proposed in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38457/1853) as well and it still wouldn't work! If anyone can tell me whats going on, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem. Blender hides options depending if you are in Blender Render Mode, Cycles, or Game mode. Its kind of frustrating actually.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably easier to just tell you what the default presets are:

- Cotton: Steps 5, Mass 0.3, Structural 15, Bend 0.5, Spring 5
- Denim: Steps 12, Mass 1, Structural 40, Bend 10, Spring 25
- Leather: Steps 15, Mass 0.4, Structural 80, Bend 150, Spring 25
- Rubber: Steps 7, Mass 3, Structural 15, Bend 25, Spring 25
- Silk: Steps 5, Mass 0.15, Structure 5, Bend 0.05, Spring 0

These are as of 2.77.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling Blender? (I guess if you have a complex start-up file it would make sense to save a copy of that before reinstalling.)